# Why is the distribution of Dark Matter in the Universe inhomogeneous?

Tags: cosmology, dark-matter, galaxies

As far as I know, there exist galaxies containing lots of DM and other galaxies with almost no DM at all.
This implies that the distribution of DM in the Universe is inhomogeneous. Do we have any idea about why this is the case? I am looking for the some solid proposals that address this observation.

Comment: Why should it be perfectly homogenous? The initial conditions of the Universe were probably not perfectly homogeneous (indeed the CMB temperature fluctuations confirm ths), and gravity will tend to make any initial overdensities become more dense and underdensities become less dense as matter falls into potential wells created by initially dense regions.

Comment: Aha, thanks! So one proposal is that the initial conditions were not homogeneous, and that carried on and got enhanced by the effects of gravity. And the assumption is that this would be enough to create the current distribution of DM in the observable universe.

Comment: Right. This is all part of the "standard model" of cosmology. Although an important parameter is the length scale of the homogenities. On the scale of galaxy clusters and larger, dark matter clusters as we expect from theory. On smaller scales (individual galaxies), there are some surprising/unexplained features (for example, the core-cusp problem). But, these small scales also involve a lot of complicated physics that is difficult to model, so it's also not necessarily surprising that simple models don't work in this regime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since my comment seems to have helped, I figure I would turn it into an answer.

The initial conditions of the Universe were not perfectly homogeneous, as confirmed by observations of the CMB temperature fluctuations confirm this. Gravity will tend to make any initial overdensities become more dense and underdensities become less dense as matter falls into potential wells created by initially dense regions.

This is part of the "standard model" of cosmology, which

1. Assumes a set of almost scale invariant initial perturbations, with some small red tilt. (in fact this primordial spectrum has been measured quite well by Planck). Many cosmologists believe these initial perturbations were generated during inflation. However, there is no smoking-gun evidence that proves this beyond a reasonable doubt so there are also cosmologists who disagree.
2. Provides a theory for how the initial perturbations evolved in the primordial plasma as sound waves travelled through the plasma, and as gravity caused initial over densities to grow. These predictions are consistent with measurements of the CMB.
3. Also provides a theory for how the overdensities continued to grow, and structures form, in the Universe after recombination (ie after charged ions in the primordial plasma settled down into neutral atoms and the Universe became transparent). These predictions are consistent with measurements of large scale structure.

However, an important parameter is the length scale of the inhomogenities. On the scale of galaxy clusters and larger, dark matter clusters as we expect from theory. On smaller scales (ie, on the scale of individual galaxies), there are some surprising/unexplained features, for example: the core-cusp problem, in which N-body simulations predict that galaxies should have sharp "cores" of dark matter, which are not observed. But, these small scales also involve a lot of complicated physics that is difficult to model, so it's also not necessarily surprising that simple models don't work in this regime. Nevertheless, some people (I would say a minority of cosmologists) take this as evidence against dark matter.